# ruby httpclient gem very slow at downloading file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby, httpclient

I am using the ruby [httpclient](https://github.com/nahi/httpclient) gem to download large files. Ideally I want to be able to download files as large as 2GB. When I download the files I do not want to load up the content of the file in memory for obvious reason so I am using the get_content API of HTTPClient as follows and then writing the chunks that are passed to the block to a file,

```
HTTPClient.new.get_content(url) do |chunk|
  puts "Downloaded chunk of size #{chunk.size}"
  file.write(chunk)
end
```

This is *extremely* slow. A 10 MB file could easily take 30 seconds.

The puts in the block keeps printing out the block size as follows,

```
Downloaded chunk of size 12276
Downloaded chunk of size 4108
Downloaded chunk of size 12276
Downloaded chunk of size 4108
Downloaded chunk of size 12276
Downloaded chunk of size 4108
Downloaded chunk of size 12276
Downloaded chunk of size 4108
Downloaded chunk of size 12276
```

If you look at the chunk size of 4108/12276 it seems like that could be the problem. The chunk sizes are really small. I could not figure out how to make the chunk sizes larger.

I have used Patron which is based on libcurl and it is pretty fast at downloading but I am not too keen on introducing a dependency on libcurl for now.

**How can I make HTTPClient download faster?**

**UPDATE 10/27/2011**

I tried the two suggestion from @NaHi and here is what I found.

When I set the transparent_gzip_decompression option to true I got the following exception

```
  Zlib::StreamError: stream error: invalid window bits
    from /Users/<user>/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.2@share/gems/httpclient-2.2.0.2/lib/httpclient/session.rb:652:in `get_body'
    from /Users/<user>/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.2@share/gems/httpclient-2.2.0.2/lib/httpclient.rb:1062:in `do_get_block'
    from /Users/<user>/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.2@share/gems/httpclient-2.2.0.2/lib/httpclient.rb:866:in `do_request'
    from /Users/<user>/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.2@share/gems/httpclient-2.2.0.2/lib/httpclient.rb:953:in `protect_keep_alive_disconnected'
    from /Users/<user>/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.2@share/gems/httpclient-2.2.0.2/lib/httpclient.rb:865:in `do_request'
    from /Users/<user>/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.2@share/gems/httpclient-2.2.0.2/lib/httpclient.rb:938:in `follow_redirect'
    from /Users/<user>/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.2@share/gems/httpclient-2.2.0.2/lib/httpclient.rb:577:in `get_content'
```

When I set the header to 'Accept-Encoding' => 'gzip,deflate' I did see an improve in performance. A 7296502 byte file that was earlier taking 24 seconds now takes 16 seconds. So that helps. In comparison however **patron** downloads the same file in 1.5 seconds. So I'm still far from achieving the same kind of performance with **httpclient**.

Comment: httpclient yields response chunks based on HTTP response from server. You cannot change chunk size... If Patron/curl works well, adding {'Accept-Encoding' => 'gzip,deflate'} as a extra HTTP header might help. Setting HTTPClient#:transparent_gzip_decompression = true might help, too.

Comment: Thanks for trying. I fixed that Zlib bug at JRuby side and transparent_gzip_decompression should work with jruby/1.6.5 (the latest.)  Perf difference from patron is interesting... Pure Ruby httpclient should be a little slower but x10 slower is unexpected. Can you let me know the URL you're using?

Comment: @NaHi I tried the transparent_gzip_compression with JRuby 1.6.5 now I do not get any exception but that option does not have a positive effect on download speeds. The url I am using is from a custom java service that is in development and runs on the Jetty server.

Comment: how fast does it download if your remove the `puts` line from your block?